# TeamCity Kotlin DSL - Dynamically generate `BuildType`s

Tags: kotlin, teamcity, dsl

I am trying to use the Kotlin DSL for TeamCity to dynamically generate build configurations.
In particular, I am looking to create a function to generate `BuildType`s from parameters.

However, I am having a hard time generating objects that [`buildType()`](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/app/dsl-documentation/-team-city%20-kotlin%20-d-s-l/jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin/-project/build-type.html) is happy with.
Consider the following minimal example:

```kotlin
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2019_2.*

version = "2021.2"

fun bar() = object : BuildType({ name = "bar" }) {}

project {
    description = "Example"
    buildType(bar())
}
```

```bash
$ mvn -o org.jetbrains.teamcity:teamcity-configs-maven-plugin:generate 
[...]
[ERROR] Validation error: BuildType(uuid='', id='null', name='bar'): mandatory 'id' property is not specified
```

The compilation complains that the `id` property hasn't been specified.
However, the following compiles fine (note that I am not explicitly setting any `id` property):

```kotlin
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2019_2.*

version = "2021.2"

object Foo : BuildType({
    name = "foo"
})

project {
    description = "Example"
    buildType(Foo)
}
```

```bash
$ mvn -o org.jetbrains.teamcity:teamcity-configs-maven-plugin:generate
[...]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.924 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-28T16:29:39+01:00
```

I am confused, as I believe that both examples are semantically equivalent...

Am I misunderstanding something in Kotlin, or with the TeamCity DSL? Is there dark magic at play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in the second case TeamCity sets id from object name which is `Foo` in your example while in the first case:

1. Object doesn't have a name
2. Moreover, you could call `bar()` multiple times and there must be a way for TeamCity to assign different id for each call

So you should somehow explicitly set id in `bar()` for example

```
fun bar(buildName: String) = object : BuildType({
  name = buildName
  id = AbsoluteId(buildName.toId())
}) {}
```